How to read a Barcode from a PDFDocument using Vision?
I need to read a barcode from a PDF document. It is created from data received via a Share Extension.
First, I try to parse each PDF page into a UIImage. If nothing is found, I try to "split" each page vertically into two and try detecting again.
The problem is that it works on some iPhone models, but there are other iPhone models where it doesn't work at all.
It works fine on iPhone 7 and iPhone 14 Pro Max, but doesn't work on iPhone 6 and iPhone 11.
What am I doing wrong?
extension PDFPage {
    // MARK: - Public Methods

    func renderToImages() -> [UIImage] {
        let topImage = generateHelfedImage(cutype: .top)
        let bottomImage = generateHelfedImage(cutype: .bot)
        return [
            topImage ?? UIImage(),
            bottomImage ?? UIImage()
        ]
    }

    func renderToImage() -> UIImage {
        let pageBounds = self.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
        let fullImage = generateImage(height: pageBounds.size.height)
        return fullImage ?? UIImage()
    }

    // MARK: - Private Methods

    private enum CutType {
        case top
        case bot
    }

    private func generateHelfedImage(cutype: CutType) -> UIImage? {
        let pageBounds = self.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
        let render = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(
            width: pageBounds.width,
            height: cutype == .top ? pageBounds.height / 2 : pageBounds.height)
        )
        let imageBounds = CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: pageBounds.size.width,
                                 height: pageBounds.size.height)
        let image = render.image { context in
            UIColor.white.set()
            context.fill(imageBounds)
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: cutype == .bot ? pageBounds.height / 2 : pageBounds.height)
            context.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
            draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context.cgContext)
        }
        return image.resizeTo(targetSize: pageBounds.size, scale: image.scale)
    }

    private func generateImage(height: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let pageBounds = self.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
        let renderSize = CGSize(
            width: pageBounds.width,
            height: pageBounds.height
        )
        let imageBounds = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: renderSize.width,
            height: renderSize.height
        )
        let render = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: renderSize)
        let image = render.image { context in
            UIColor.orange.set()
            context.fill(imageBounds)
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: height)
            context.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
            draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context.cgContext)
        }
        return image
    }
}

extension PDFDocument {
    func convertToImages(halfPages: Bool) -> [UIImage] {
        var images: [UIImage] = []
        for pageIndex in 0..<pageCount {
            guard let page = page(at: pageIndex) else { continue }
            if halfPages {
                let imagesHalfed = page.renderToImages()
                images += imagesHalfed
            } else {
                let fullImage = page.renderToImage()
                images.append(fullImage)
            }
        }
        return images
    }
}


enum VNRequestType: CaseIterable {
    case code

    func request<T>(completion: @escaping([T]?) -> Void) -> VNRequest {
        switch self {
        case .code:
            let request = VNDetectBarcodesRequest { request, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    return completion(nil)
                }
                var observations: [VNBarcodeObservation] = []
                for result in request.results ?? [] {
                    if let observation = result as? VNBarcodeObservation {
                        observations.append(observation)
                    }
                }
                if observations.isEmpty {
                    return completion(nil)
                }
                let findedCodes = observations.map { ($0.payloadStringValue, $0.symbology) }
                return completion(findedCodes as? [T])
            }
            request.symbologies = [
                .upce,
                .code39,
                .code93,
                .code128,
                .ean8,
                .ean13,
                .aztec,
                .pdf417,
                .itf14,
                .dataMatrix
            ]
            return request
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func resizeTo(targetSize: CGSize, scale: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIImage {
        let currentSize = self.size

        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / currentSize.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / currentSize.height

        var newSize: CGSize
        if widthRatio > heightRatio {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
        } else {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
        }
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, scale)
        self.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage ?? UIImage()
    }

    func detect<T>(
        content type: [T].Type,
        with requests: [VNRequestType],
        completion: @escaping([T]?) -> Void
    ) throws {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return }
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage)
        let request = requests.map { $0.request(completion: completion) }
        try handler.perform(request)
    }
}


I tried to use thumbnail too
